# \pgf plot: fatal compile error when replacing quadratic with linear function

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-pic

I'm trying to slightly modify code that graphs 2 quadratic functions (h/t @TorbjørnT). The revision should graph 1 quadratic and 1 linear function.

But when I replace `\addplot [red] {x^2};` with `\addplot [red] {-2x-9};`, a fatal compile error occurs:

`` Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `x' or \`x-' (in '-2x-9'). at ./main.tex, line 18. ``

I understand that the log file is indicating that the code is treating `x` as a math operator instead of a variable. I tried enclosing expression in `$ $` to no avail.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated as I'm a newbie to pgfplot.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      % width and height if axis, adjust to your liking
      width=7cm,
      height=6cm,
      xtick=\empty, % remove all ticks from x-axis
      ytick=\empty, % ditto for y-axis
      xlabel=$x$, 
      ylabel=$y$,
      axis lines=center, % default is to make a box around the axis
      domain=-2.5:2.5,
      samples=100]
    \addplot [red] {-2x-9};
%replace {x^2} with {-2x-9}
    \addplot [blue] {2(x+4)^2-5};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to write the `*` out: `-2*x-9`, `2*(x+4)^2-5`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Perfect. Thanks for the fix. Would you possibly have time to show me how to place the coordinate plane grid behind the graphs? Many thanks!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I don't see anywhere to mark your answer as "SOLVED". sorry.